# MySQL Can I split the group further if need it after using group by method based on the grouping condition

Tags: mysql, sql

So I hope I can explain my question clear

I wonder if there is a way to further split the grouping if need it based on the grouping condition

```
create Table if NOT EXISTS click_action (
  cid int(3) NOT NULL,
  session_id int(5) NOT NULL,
  click_val int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(cid)
 );
 
INSERT INTO click_action (cid, session_id, click_val)
  VALUES (111, 12345, 2),
(121, 12345, 3),
(131, 12345, 4),
(141, 12344, 2),
(151, 12344, 3),
(161, 12344, 8),
(171, 12344, 9)
```

Above I set a small table with a cid, session id, click_val and use cid as a primary key. I insert some test value under the create table statement. I want to generate a query which will group by session id and return a randomly generated session grouping id, the max click val and min click val in the grouping. However after group by session id. I want to make sure there isn't a huge gap greater than 3 between the sorted click val value in each grouping. If there is, we split between the gap.

So for example given the test value I inserted. If we first group by session_id, we can get first group which has cid 111, 121, and 131. If we check the click_val in the group which is value 3,4 and 5, we find there is no gap larger than 3 so this grouping is accepted. However in second grouping using session id 12344, we can group together with cid value of 141, 151, 161 and 171. However if we want to check the gap, we first sort based on click val, which we get 2, 3, 8, 9. Then we can find out there is a larger than 3 click val gap between value 3 and 8. So when that happen I want my query to split this group into cid 141, 151 and another group with cid 161,171

The final query that will return should be

```
random id, 3, 4
random id, 2, 3
random id, 8, 9
```

I been stuck on this problem on some time now, I was wondering how can I do this or is there any build in SQL function I am not aware of that can help me solve the task?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT cid, session_id, click_val, 
                 (click_val - COALESCE(LAG(click_val) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY cid), -3)) > 3 too_wide
          FROM click_action ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT cid, session_id, click_val,
                 SUM(too_wide) OVER (ORDER BY session_id, cid) random_id
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT random_id, session_id, MIN(click_val), MAX(click_val)
FROM cte2
GROUP BY random_id, session_id;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f6f80320bf630881869c1cee733d2b3

If you want to have really random `random_id` values then generate them additionally checking their uniqueness.